# Solving this indefinite integral

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find the exact value of this definite integral.

$
\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{(40\cos(5t))^2 + (12\cos(4t))^2} \ dt
$

I've managed to simplify it a little bit, but I do not know how to continue.

$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4} 4\sqrt{100(\cos(5t))^2 + 9(\cos(4t))^2} \ dt $

How can this be solved?

Edit: It seems I've made errors in typing the equations...

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Could you also manage to make your formula a bit more readable?

Comment: My first instinct is to "split" $ \ cos(5t)\ $ into $ \ cos(4t + t)\ $ and then use trig identities. However, it's not obvious whether or not this will get us to the answer. It's worth a try though

Comment: What is the relation between the two integrals ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that a closed form would exist even if we can simplify the first one
$$\int \sqrt{144 \cos ^2(4 t)+40 \cos ^2(5 t)} \,dt=\int \sqrt{72 \cos (8 t)+20 \cos (10 t)+92}\,dt$$

Numerical integration between the given bounds gives
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{72 \cos (8 t)+20 \cos (10 t)+92}\,dt=7.04444037940539968801099\cdots$$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

*Just for the fun of it*, this number is very close to
$$\frac{443 \pi ^2+992 \pi-388 }{171 \pi ^2-337 \pi+379}$$ corresponding to a relative error of $2.9\times 10^{-18}\text{%}$.

Comment: $\left(40\cos(5t)\right)^2\ne40\cos^2(5t)$